# struct alignas(x) on eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++14

Hi I am running eclipse mars version on linux

```
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600

Linux:  Fedora21 3.18.5-201.fc21.x86_64
g++: (GCC) 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1)
```

but the following code is showing incorrectly as a syntax error in the eclipse editor with yellow underlines and a question mark that says syntax error even though the code compiles just fine. All other c++14 syntax works just fine after twiddling with the settings a bit and no other issues are found as I have the -std=c++14 flag etc turned on and my __cplusplus macro is correct. Eclipse recognizes alignas(x) for other items but not after the struct keyword. Any ideas?

```
// Eclipse flags this as a syntax error with yellow underlines and a question mark
struct alignas(64) Test { 
int64_t x;
};

// this works fine
        alignas(64) const static double table[] =
        {
            1.0,           
            0.1,           
            0.01,          
            0.001,         
        } ;
```

Comment: FWIW, it works on my cygwin installation of g++ 4.9.3.

Comment: In `following code is giving a syntax error`, what is *giving you a syntax error*? At least the last time I used it, eclipse's static analyzer didn't understand all of c++11 let alone c++14. I haven't used it lately, so my experience may be outdated.

Comment: added text to better explain syntax error. It is the Eclipse CDT giving the syntax error